# the general linear groups - solvable

Tags: group-theory

I'm doing some experimental mathematics and I'm in the situation where I need an answer to the question:

Consider the general linear groups $\operatorname{GL}(2,10)$, $\operatorname{GL}(4,10)$ (the general linear groups of degree $10$ over the fields of order $2$ and $4$) and $\operatorname{GL}(2,15)$, $\operatorname{GL}(4,15)$.

Are these groups solvable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group#Finite_fields):

The projective special linear groups $PSL(n, F_q)$ for a finite field $F_q$  are finite simple groups whenever $n$ is at least $2$, with two exceptions:$PSL(2, F_2)$ and $PSL(2, F_3)$.

Since $PSL$ is a quotient group of $SL$, then $GL$ cannot be soluble.